# Save a copy of my workbook as "w.e" and then Friday's date from next week

Tags: excel, vba

I added this line to the end of one of my modules:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ("w.e " & Format(Date + 14 - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday), "DD.MM.YY") & ".xls")
```

And so far it seems to work, however most of the code I have taken from places and I haven't tested it enough to know if it may fall down anywhere.
The purpose of this file is a timesheet for each week, so each week is named "w.e 11.10.19.xls" for example, then I need the new file to be one week later than that.
Can anyone advise if the above code is doing as I need or if there are scenarios that it will fall down?

Comment: Don't use periods in file names, those are used for extensions.

Comment: Doesn't seem to have caused any issues so far, or whilst doing this process manually at least.  Do you think that will trip up the code?

Comment: Not the code, maybe the os and is definitely bad practice. use - or _ instead.

Answer (score 1):

The dot (`.`) is not a [special symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications#user-defined-datetime-formats) for date formatting, so it will always remain `.` (unlike, e.g., `/` that will be replaced with the current locale's date separator).

Hence, your particular format string is safe.

If you don't wont to consult documentation on which characters are non-special, you can always add a slash before them to make them non-special even when they otherwise would be:

```vb
Format(Date + 14 - Weekday(Date, vbSaturday), "DD\.MM\.YY")
```